# Why my API response data doesn't display in a table ( React JS )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have already API responses and I want to show them in a table format.But it doesn't work. I took columns data from hostdatatablesource, and for rows, I called API in this page.

And I get this error:

react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `rows` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(DataGrid)`, expected `array`.

```
import "./datatable.scss";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { userColumns } from "../../hostdatatablesource";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import useAxiosPrivate from "../../hooks/useAxiosPrivate";

const HOST_URL = '/organizers';

const Datatable = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const axiosPrivate = useAxiosPrivate();
  
      useEffect(() => {
          let isMounted = true;
          const controller = new AbortController();
          const fetchData = async () => {
              try {
         const response = await axiosPrivate.get(HOST_URL,
            {
            signal: controller.signal
            });
            isMounted && setData(response.data);
                  } 
      catch (err) {
        if (err.response) {
          // Not in the 200 response range 
          console.log(err.response.data);
          console.log(err.response.status);
          console.log(err.response.headers);
        } else {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        }
      }
    }
    fetchData();

    return () =>{
          isMounted = false;
          controller.abort();
    }
  }, [])

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setData(data.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };
  const actionColumn = [
    {
      field: "action",
      headerName: "Action",
      width: 200,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <div className="cellAction">
            <Link to="/host/Hostsingle" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
              <div className="viewButton">View</div>
            </Link>
            <div
              className="deleteButton"
              onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row.id)}
            >
              Delete
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div className="datatable">
      <div className="datatableTitle">
        Add New Host
        <Link to="/host/new" className="link">
          Add Host
        </Link>
      </div>
      <DataGrid
        className="datagrid"
        rows={data}
        columns={userColumns.concat(actionColumn)}
        pageSize={9}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[9]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Datatable;
```

Comment: What does the API respond with? Is it what you expect? Adding `console.log(response.data);` before the `isMounted && setData(response.data);` line is probably helpful, or simply check the browser devtools' network tab. Based on the error message it sounds like the API response is an object of some shape; the `DataGrid` component requires that the `rows` property is an array.

Comment: How does `response.data` look like when you log it in console?

Answer (score 0):

Your `response.data` must be an array. So, check if the `setData(response.data)` is an array or not. You can use `console.log(response.data)` to be sure about it.